# Does the set of scalene triangles include the special cases of isosceles and equilateral triangles?

Tags: geometry, terminology

A math question starts:

> $\triangle$ABC is a scalene triangle ...

From this should I imply the solution must never work when $\triangle$ABC is isosceles or equilateral? That is to ask, does the set of scalene triangles include the special cases of isosceles and equilateral triangles?

[Can an equilateral triangle be an isosceles triangle, too?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/991767/can-an-equilateral-triangle-be-an-isosceles-triangle-too)

Comment: isosceles: at least 2 sides equal. this includes equilateral. But once I saw scalene as all unequal sides, and some other time it was one angle bigger than right angle. (don't know which is right-- maybe google it.)

Comment: @coffeemath  I think "one angle bigger than right" is "obtuse", I  doubt "scalene" is ever used that way. I agree that an equilateral triangle is isosceles but that a scalene triangle can't be isosceles. Wolfram agrees.

Comment: @EthanBolker So do we have any definitive def of scalene?

Comment: A triangle that might be equilateral, isosceles, or have three sides all different is called "a triangle."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you'll find debate on the in/exclusiveness of "scalene" the way you do with "isosceles" vs "equilateral" (or "rectangle" vs "square", or "trapezoid" vs "parallelogram", etc). The term seems to exist *precisely* to guarantee that there are no symmetries that can cause elements —say, an altitude, median, and/or angle bisector from a vertex— to coincide, so that constructions relying on distinct elements don't degenerate. At the moment, I can't think of a particularly-good example that "goes bad" for isosceles triangles, but I'll note that the [Euler line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_line) is undefined for equilaterals, due to the coincidence of all the key "triangle centers" that would otherwise uniquely determine it.

Incidentally, according to the ["Earliest Known Uses of Some of the Words of Mathematics"](http://jeff560.tripod.com/s.html) pages, "scalenum" excluded isosceles from way-back-when.

> In Sir Henry Billingsley’s 1570 translation of Euclid’s *Elements*, *scalenum* is used as a noun: "Scalenum is a triangle, whose three sides are all unequall."

It might be interesting to check *Elements* to see to what degree the passages using the term *needed* the triangles in question to be asymmetric.

As for whether you should (*ahem*) "[*infer*] the solution must never work when $\triangle ABC$ is isosceles or equilateral" ... It's possible that symmetry will cause a problem's solution to fail completely (think Euler line), but it's also possible that an isosceles/equilateral configuration amounts to a "limiting form" of the property under discussion; in the latter case, such a form might well be considered valid from a suitable point of view, but the presenter may not (yet) want to burden the discussion with such nuances. So, never infer "never".

In, say, textbook exercises or contest problems, my *sense* of things is that the term "scalene" is often the author's assurance that the reader needn't fear *gotcha* degeneracies.

Answer (score 2):

One observation. If the set of scalene triangles included isosceles and equilateral triangles, then it would actually be the set of all triangles. So *scalene triangle* would just mean *triangle* and the term would be redundant.

Clearly this would be true whether or not isosceles triangles were defined as including equilateral ones.

A proof might consider scalene triangles in order to guarantee that it works for arbitrary side lengths—but this is different from defining all triangles as scalene.